# An example of a monomorphism that is not an equalizer in "Abstract and Concrete Categories -- The Joy of Cats"

Tags: category-theory, abstract-algebra

I am sorry, maybe i am just confused or have not understood some definition, but i do not understand the following remark in [Abstract and Concrete Categories -- The Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) on page 117:

> $\mathbb Z \hookrightarrow \mathbb Q$ is a monomorphism in **Sgr** (the category of semigroups) that is not regular (not an [equalizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equalizer_%28mathematics%29#In_category_theory) of two morphisms).

It seems to me it *is* an equalizer of the two natural morphisms $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q *_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q$ (the free product of two copies of the group $\mathbb Q$ with amalgamated copies of $\mathbb Z$).

Where am i mistaken? Thanks.

---

**Update.** There are simpler pairs of morphisms for which $\mathbb Z \hookrightarrow \mathbb Q$ would be an equalizer: consider different morphisms $\mathbb Q \to (\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)\oplus(\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the authors meant $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Q$ as semigroups with respect to the *multiplication* and not the addition.

Comment: did they answer to your mail?

Comment: Yes, from their answers i have understood that it was about multiplication and not addition. Maybe it was mentioned somewhere in the book, but i did not read all.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an equalizer to me.  Perhaps the authors meant the inclusion homomorphism of $\mathbb N$ (rather than $\mathbb Z$) into $\mathbb Q$. This is not an equalizer.  Indeed, if two homomorphisms from $\mathbb Q$ into any semigroup $S$ agree on $\mathbb N$, then they must also agree on $\mathbb Z$, because inverses in $S$ are unique when they exist.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, maybe i will write to the authors.

Comment: It would be simpler then to give $\mathbb N \hookrightarrow \mathbb Z$ as an example.

Comment: @Alexey Yes; my answer was based not on making the example as simple as possible but on keeping it as close as possible to what you quoted. In other words, assume just a single typo rather than two.

Comment: idk, do semigroup homs have to send inverses to inverses?  if we consider everything as monoids then yes...